# How to avoid multiple recordings when recording with Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player, audio-recording

When I record music to my PC Windows Media Player, it copies it more than once, sometimes 3 times.

How can I rectify this problem? I am using Windows7 on a HP touch screen PC.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try resetting WMP's media library. First note that resetting the library will make you lose all current play counts, and possibly ratings too. Then, follow these steps:

- Reboot the PC.
- Go to Start, type **services.msc** in the Search field, and press Enter. In Services, find the Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service. If its status is **Started**, double-click the service and click **Stop**.
- Go to Start, type **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft** in the Search field, and press Enter. This folder will open up in Windows Explorer.
- In this folder, delete the **Media Player** folder. If you can't see the folder, then it's probably hidden. Set Explorer to show hidden files and folders, and to show protected system files.
- Start WMP, your library will have been reset and will be rebuilt. Check if the duplicates are removed.